Unexpected any. Specify a different type
I want infer something in typescript like this:
export type InferSomething<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<infer U> ? U : never;

This works but generates the error https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-explicit-any/ in my IDE.
I generally like the rule, because any is usually very bad in TS but here I use it for inference and any does not cause any harm.
I am aware that I can disable the rule locally or globally but my question is:
Is it possible to adjust my inference that I don't have to disable the specific rule?

Use never instead of any[]; see linked q/a for more information.
